# "Adrián" como "nido de urracas"

Tags: etimología, historia, palabras-raras, animales, cuerpo-humano

Adrián, aparte de las acepciones bien conocidas (**callo de los pies** hasta 1884 y **juanete** desde entonces hasta la actualidad), tuvo una acepción adicional, que apareció en el suplemento del DLE de 1884 y estuvo presente hasta la edición de 1989, y que persiste aún en el diccionario de María Moliner:

> **Nido de urracas**.

¿Cómo apareció y luego desapareció la acepción "nido de urracas"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: Todo es un embrollo originado en el siglo XVI por una mala traducción de *nids d'agaches*, literalmente y en idioma [picardo](https://dle.rae.es/picardo) "callo".**

---

Para dar respuesta a esta pregunta me he valido de un documento recogido por la biblioteca virtual Miguel de Cervantes, titulado *[Voces internacionales en dos direcciones](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra/voces-internacionales-en-dos-direcciones-0/)*, de Germà Colón Domènech. Comencemos con un paseo por la historia. Fíjate en las siguientes entradas de los diccionarios del siglo XVII:

- *Palet*, 1604: Adrianes, *Nids de Pie* (literalmente, "nido de cuervos").
- *Oudin*, 1607: Adrianes, *nids de Pies*.
- *Vittori*, 1609: Adriánes, *nids de Pies*, nido di gazza ("nido de urraca").
- *Franciosini*, 1620: Adrianes, nido che fa la gazzera ("nido que hace la urraca").

En el caso de Palet, ese es el único significado que se le da a la palabra. En los casos de Oudin y Franciosini, ese significado alterna con el relativo al pie. Algunos diccionarios posteriores mantienen estas acepciones:

- *Sobrino*, 1705: Adrianes, m. *Nids de Pies.*
- *Stevens*, 1706: Adriánes, Magpies Nests ("nido de urracas").

Ya a partir de aquí, el *Autoridades* de 1726 recoge la voz en plural con el significado de "callo" (el de 1770 recoge la voz en singular). La voz en plural aparece con este significado en un diccionario español por primera vez en el *Castro y Rossi* de 1852:

> Adrianes, s. m. p. (Ant.) Nido que hacen las urracas o picazas.

Curioso que hace referencia a que la palabra la tomó del *Franciosini* de 1620, y además la marca como "antigua".

Y ahora viene el *plot twist*. Resulta que Palet y Oudin citan entre sus fuentes al *Recueil de dictionaires francoys, espaignolz et latins* de H. Hornkens, publicado en Bruselas en 1599. Palet y Oudin, de hecho, tomaron multitud de entradas de este diccionario para componer los suyos. Y resulta que ambos metieron bien la pata porque desconocían una expresión del dialecto picardo, del norte de Francia, que era la correspondiente a la siguiente entrada del Hornkens:

> «**nids d'agaches**, durillons - *adrianes* - clavi, caelosa, pedis granae» (s.v. *nids*).

"Nids d'agaches" significa literalmente "nido de urracas", pero en picardo era la denominación para "callo, ojo de gallo, dureza". En francés común se usaría *oeil de perdrix*, igual que aquí existe *[ojo de gallo](https://dle.rae.es/ojo#8AJpfrM)*. En otras tierras se sustituyó *perdrix* por *agace* o *agasse*, y también *oeil* por *nid* 'nido', según el autor del estudio "probablemente a causa de una metacedeusis provocada por el sentido y la proximidad fonética entre *[üy]* y *[ni]*". Y resulta finalmente que [Horkens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henricus_Hornkens) era de Brabante, en la zona donde se usaba *nid d'agache* (la versión picarda de *agasse*), y le pareció por tanto natural escribir *nids d'agaches* y traducirlo por el español *adrianes*, "callo".

¿Qué sucedió? Que ni Palet ni Oudin conocían esta expresión, y decidieron dejarla tal cual en el diccionario, pero cambiando el picardismo *agache* (en el que reconocieron al entonces moribundo *agasse*) por el más parisino *pie*. Por tanto, en sus diccionarios aparece que *adrianes* significa en francés *nids de pie*. A partir de ahí, el resto de diccionarios tomaron esta traducción y la respetaron tal cual, pasándose al italiano *nido di gazza*, al inglés *magpie's nest* (Stevens reconoce en su prólogo haber tomado entradas del Oudin), e incluso al español *nido de urraca*.

Comment: ¡ Fascinante historia ! Por cierto, en español ojo de gallo = ojo de pollo, pero es distinto de ojo de perdiz.

Comment: @JuliusAndrewOnphalus me alegra que te haya gustado, la verdad es que a mí también me pareció fascinante. Debo agradecer a la gente del sitio de francés el haberme puesto sobre la pista del estudio que cito. ¡Y gracias por la recompensa!

Comment: Merecida - lamentablemente no  pudo ser de más de esos puntos